# Please help me prove this about Lyapunov Exponents!

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

[image]

Here, $\lambda(y_0)$ denotes the [Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent#Definition_of_the_maximal_Lyapunov_exponent) of the logistic orbit starting at $y_0$.

I tried starting like this: We have $F(x_k)=ax_k(1-x_k)$. Hence $|F'(x_k)|=|a-2a x_k|$, but I have no idea how to compute $$\lambda(x_0)= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \ln | F'(x_i)|.$$

Comment: This [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent#Definition_of_the_maximal_Lyapunov_exponent) ?

Comment: Yes, the same. It is a measure of the sensitive dependence on initial conditions of a given map.

Comment: Please check if my edit is ok

Comment: Thank you, it is. The part I'm stuck on is the range $3<a<1+\sqrt6$ -- I have no idea how to incorporate that when calculating $\lambda(x_0)$.

Comment: Please see equation (57) [here](http://links.uwaterloo.ca/pmath370docs/week5.pdf). You probably saw a proof in your course that the logistic map will alternate in a $2$-cycle for $3<a<1+\sqrt6$

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking it out now.